# Container casting

Tags: c++, containers, static-cast

I have two classes and my conversion methods:

```
class A;
class B;

class A
{
    ...
};

class B
{
    ...

    static B fromA(A a)
    {
        B b;
        // ... some property conversions from A to B
        return b;
    }
    operator A()
    {
         // ... some property conversions from this(B) to A
        return A
    }
}
```

As one can see I defined a cast (for B -> A) + a static conversion (for A -> B) inside class B. It is forbidden to define any cast or conversion inside class A.

Suppose I have two vectors:

```
vector<vector<A> > vecA; // pre-defined
vector<vector<B> > vecB; // to be casted from vecA
```

**What is the optimal(fastest) way to achieve data conversion between those, instead of my ugly solution:**

```
using namespace std;

vecB.resize(vecA.size());
for(int i = 0; i<vecA.size(); i++)
{
    vecB[i].resize(vecA[i].size());
    for(int j = 0; j<vecA[i].size(); j++)
    {
        vecB[i][j] = B::fromA(vecA[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define operator= for B

```
B::operator=(const A& a)
{
// actual code to copy from a to b.
}
```

in your code change the line

```
vecB[i][j] = B::fromA(vecA[i][j]);
```

to

```
vecB[i][j] = vecA[i][j];
```

it will eliminate many temporary A & B objects that are created in your original code.

Also instead of using vecB[i][j] use iterators. Following code may have some syntax errors

```
vecB.resize(vecA.size());

vector<vector<A> >::const_iterator itA1;
vector<vector<B> >::const_iterator itB1;
vector<A> >::const_iterator itA2;
vector<B> >::const_iterator itB2;


for(itA1=vecA.begin(), itB1= vecB.begin(); 
         itA1 != vecA.end(); 
        ++itA1, ++itB1)
{
    for(itA2 = (*itA1).begin(), itB2=(*itB1).begin(); 
      itA2 != (*itA1).end(); 
      ++itA2, ++itB2)
    {
        (*itB2) = *itA2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `std::vector::resize()` before the copies

Answer (score 1):

You can use algorithms and iterators instead of hand-crafted `for` loops if you want (that might be a bit faster if your standard library implementation is heavily optimised), but the core complexity remains the same - you have to convert each element individually, no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

instead of defining:

```
static B fromA(A a);
```

define:

`B(A a)` as a conversion constructor

generally this is avoided by using the `explicit` keyword but here this seems to be exactly what you want since you need to construct a B from A

this would simplify:

```
vecB[i][j] = B::fromA(vecA[i][j]);
```

to:

```
vecB[i][j] = vecA[i][j];
```

which looks like a good candidate for `std::copy

Comment: Thanks, std::copy has same complexity of two for loops. However, elimination of temporary B object with a constructor or some operator seems to be critical.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to make your code a bit shorter and easier to read. However I think you will get best performance if you define the method `B fromA(A a)` a void method that takes an output parameter of type `B&`. I.e. make your method declaration `static void fromA(const A&, B&)`. This way for pre-c++11 code you will avoid a copy of the returned object.

Alternatively make the method `fromA` instance method instead of a static method and again make it void - the method would modify the current instance. Another option is as pointed in other answers - to create a constructor of B that takes a `const A&` as its only parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an implicit conversion constructor to convert `A` to `B`, rather than a named function:

```
B(A const & a) {
    // ... some property conversions from A to B
}
```

Now you could convert a single vector with something like

```
std::vector<B> vecB(vecA.begin(), vecA.end());  // declare a new vector
vecB.assign(vecA.begin(), vecA.end());          // reassign an existing vector
```

You'll still need a loop to reassign a vector of vectors; perhaps something like:

```
vecB.clear();
vecB.reserve(vecA.size());
for (auto const & vA : vecA) {
    vecB.push_back(std::vector<B>(vA.begin(), vA.end()));
}
```

This is no faster than your version, but involves writing less code.

Comment: isnt push_back slower than resize+assignment ?

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı: Not if you've reserved enough space beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write nice code you can use either `std::transform` or `std::assign`, or `std::for_each` but if you want fast code then it will be hard to write something faster than this:

```
vecB.resize(vecA.size());
for (unsigned int i = 0, asize = vecA.size(); i < asize; i++)
{
    const vector<A> & vin = vecA[i];
    vector<A> & vout = vecB[i];

    vout.resize(vin.size());
    for (unsigned int j = 0, bsize = vout.size(); j < bsize; j++)
    {
        vout[j].createFromA(vin[j]);
    }
}
```

Notice the `asize` and `bsize` initialization is done like such to prevent aliasing problems.
Also `createFromA` should be a member function that directly initializes the class members without other class copy/assignment.